# Convert Flux<Document> to Flux<Object> or List<Object>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, bson

I have an object of

```
class Employee {

    private String salary;
    private String empId;
    private String departmentId;
    private String status;
}
```

and one method that returns Flux <Document>, Document is of type org.bson.Document, example

```
[
    {
        "empId": "B123",
        "salary": "1000",
        "departmentId": "winna",
        "status": "START"
    },
    {
        "empId": "A123",
        "salary": "2000",
        "departmentId": "dinna",
        "status": "COMPLETED"
    }
]
```

How to convert Flux <Document> to Flux <Employee> or List <Employee> in JAVA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one I am using. It is perfectly working fine. `studentService.getAll()` returns `Flux<Student>` using map I can convert into `Flux<String>`. You need to consider @Ikatiforis answer.

[image]

In your case following should work

```
documentFlux.map(d-> {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            //set values
            return e;
        });
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't work as the first flux is Flux<Document>. Document is org.bson.Document so it does not have getters to get values and set it into new object.

Comment: updated the question as well, sorry i missed that

Comment: Then your question is about bson into java object.

Comment: Then inside map method you need to convert bson to json. And then json to your object. You can refer this.https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-bson-to-json

Answer (score 3):

`Flux` API is part of the [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) library. If you wonder which operator fits your case, I would suggest you go through the [Which operator do I need?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator)
section of the official reference guide.

In this case, you need the following [part](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.values):

> I want to transform existing data:
>
> on a 1-to-1 basis (eg. strings to their length): map (Flux|Mono)

So, you need the `map` operator to transform `Document` instance to `Employee`.

Comment: i used map, it did not work

Comment: @ShrutiGusain update your question.

Comment: updated question is available now